# How to create a SHA1/MD5 Fingerprint on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sha1, mobile-application

[image: Screenshot]

I am new to Android studio programming. Here I want to run **signing report**, so that I can get the **SHA1 fingerprint**. When I open the **gradle** window, it is just giving me some options, as in the screenshot given above. The option **signing report** is not mentioned anywhere. I hadn't done anything on the project. I have just created a new project.In this situation, how can I get the SHA1 fingerprint. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have founded the answer myself.

If the signing report is missing on your gradle file and you need to get the **SHA-1 fingerprint** :

1.Open the **project**

2.Click on File menu -> Select New -> Click on Google -> Select **Google Maps Activity**

3.On the resulting dialog box, simply click **finish**.

4.Open it's **XML** File.

5.SHA-1 fingerprint will be on it , marked as a **comment**.

6.After copying the SHA-1 fingerprint, simply press **Ctrl + Z** to undo creating the google maps activity.

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and try this
First Build your project ,
Go to `Gradle` and click on `Tasks` -> `Android` and then `signing report`

I had similar issue , this helped me